# with what software should I program the funduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr

1. With what software should I program the *funduino*?
2. This is really silly but can I use the *arduino* software?
3. If so what board should I assign?

Comment: you should approve some answers to your previous questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an arduino compatible board.you should program using C Language. Just assign Uno R3. You can use arduino IDE.